# infopath forms not working on sharepoint form library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, office-2016

I am using Infopath form in sharepoint form library. The forms are desgined to open in client application as there are some features not supported in browser. The issue is after upgrading to SharePoint 2016, forms are not opening when clicked. The error pop up says that, 'This action couldn't be performed because Office doesn't recognize the command it was given.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft team reported that it is a bug and they are working on it. It is now working if we update the master page to IE-11.

Answer (score 1):

Check the possible solution  [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fix-problems-opening-documents-in-sharepoint-libraries-31329fa1-4ad0-47fc-95d8-bb0c5b12a536)